# Show Log and SVN Works Only With "All Can Read" Option in authz File

Tags: svn, authorization, svn-administraton

I am using SVN and and only if I set at file authz * = r then I can view log messages when selecting Show Log from the context menu.

Surely this is not what I want - to allow all reads access...

I currently use @developer=rw but as I mentioned above this does not work.

Please advise

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the whole configuration file here, so my guess is that granting access to developers group doesn't work because you didn't specify members of this group in **[group]** section. Your configuration file should look like the following:

```
[group]
developers = person_a, person_b

[/]
developers = rw
```

Check [this manual for the syntax](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html).