# SVN Show Log not working

Tags: svn, authorization, svn-administraton

How can I use the show log feature without setting [/] * = r (reads to everyone/everything).

I have a couple of groups in my authz file. It Looks like this:

```
[groups]
Profs = dave,bruno,franck
Team1 = 1036091,1036103,1036087
Team2 = 1016059,1016077
[/GSS]
@Team1 = rw
[/Booking]
@Team2 = rw
[/]
@Profs = rw
```

When I add

```
[/]
* = r
```

in the file, the show log feature works. But that gives access to everyone on all the repositories.

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275505/show-log-and-svn-works-only-with-all-can-read-option-in-authz-file) has not been answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I experienced exactly the same problem. Googling did not provide with a solution, but after some experiments I found 2 solutions for this: One Work-Around and one great solution.

1. Work-Around: Add [/] * = r to the authz file (and may be * = r to you application folder in the authz file also). Try a showlog with Tortoise and may be some compare methods in Tortoise. Remove the above lines from authz file and try agin. Tortoise somehow caches that and it seems to work
2. Great solution: Add these lines to the svnserve.conf file:

anon-access = none
auth-access = write

After that it worked as expected. Seems like the solution to me.

Good luck!

Comment: tortoise caches the log, it works because it reads the cache, if you delete teh cache, or use the command line, youre screwed again.

Comment: #2 worked for me and this is better than the first one

Answer (score 0):

The svn authz file (configuration file for mod_authz_svn which provides this [Path-based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) feature) can only setup read-only (**r**) or  read-write (**rw**) access modes.
Thus, there is no possibility to grant access for particular operation as it is quite obvious that for **svn log** operation you need to have read access which in its turn will allow checkout, info, etc

However, there is a solution from WANdisco which allows to build a shield around svn server with really advanced [Access Control management](http://docs.wandisco.com/svn/ac/#6). There you can find that there is a special permission called **list** which grants access specifically for **log**, **info** and **ls** svn commands.